# Neither - Nor vs Don’t- And

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, pronouns

> 1. Alex likes neither candy nor cake.
> 2. Alex don’t like candy and cake.

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: Your first sentence is grammatically correct; your second is not. **Don't** would require a plural subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence 1. means that "Alex doesn't like candy" and "Alex doesn't like cake" are both true.
As pointed out in the comment, 2. needs a singular verb. Fixing that, we have

> 2.a Alex doesn't like candy and cake.

That is not equivalent to the first statement, because it may mean only  that Alex doesn't like the combination "candy and cake".
The equivalent of 1. is

> 3. Alex doesn't like candy or cake.